# Angular JS scope not updating from included template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-template

So I have below index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="UsersController">
<div ng-include='"assets/users/partials/template.html"'></div>
<a ng-click="get_data()">Get</a>
</div>
```

Template.html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="SearchUser" name="SearchUser" />
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('UsersController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.get_data = function(){ console.log($scope.SearchUser); };
}
]);
```

So in above case on the click anchor, I am getting undefined in the `$scope.SearchUser` scope value.
But if I take that input out of the template and put inside main HTML it works.

I checked for multiple controller declaration and other stuffs but nothing worked for me.

I am using angular 1.2.25 version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ng-include defines its own scope, which inherits from the controller scope. So SearchUser is set, but as an attribute of the child scope.

As always, the solution is to have a dot in your ng-model, and to define the outer object in the controller scope:

```
$scope.state = {};
```

and, in the HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="state.SearchUser" name="SearchUser" />
```

That way, angular will get the state field from the child scope. Since the child scope prototypically extends the controller scope, it will find it in the controller scope, and it will write the SearchUser attribute of the state object.